# run ajax after default form action?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the following code to run a PHP file using AJAX. it works fine and as it should.

However, the form that the AJAX code is on has a `default action`. for example `<form action="index.php">`

my AJAX code is this:

```
             <script>
        $('#select').change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if (selectedValue === 'Yes') {
                  $(function(){
      $('form').submit(function(e){
        var thisForm = $(this);
        //Prevent the default form action
        e.preventDefault();
            //Post the form to the send script
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'mySecond.php',
              data: thisForm.serialize(),
              //Wait for a successful response
        });
      })
    });
            } else {

            }
        });
</script>
```

I know that `e.preventDefault();` means it will get rid of the default form action and it will only execute the AJAX call.

So, is there any way, to execute both `AJAX` and the `default form action`? or maybe, one after the other?

P.S. i did remove the `e.preventDefault();` and it will stop the AJAX call working!

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot execute both AJAX and the `default form action` since `default form action` will reload current page (or redirect to another page)

Answer (score 1):

Not as such.

You can't perform the default form action and then perform the Ajax without setting up the page that is the response to the form submission to make the Ajax request when it loads.

You can't perform the Ajax request and then allow the default form submission to continue because Ajax is asynchronous, so it wouldn't complete before the form submission triggered.

You could cancel the default form action, perform the Ajax request and then (in the response handler for the Ajax request) submit the form programatically (by calling its `submit()` method).

You'd probably be better off using the normal form submission, as a single request, to perform both tasks and not bother with Ajax at all though.

Comment: That makes sense. any chance of an example?

Comment: `ref_to_form.submit()`

Comment: a bit more details would be great! where does that go? what does that mean?

Comment: *where does that go* — "in the response handler for the Ajax request"

Comment: *what does that mean* — It means "Submit this form"

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the normal form submission, as a single request, to perform both tasks and not bother with Ajax at all though..I don't agree with you. i need to run the AJAX only if the select option is selected and it is Yes. unless there is another way of doing that I am not aware of?

Comment: So move the logic to test if the option is selected to the server too.

Comment: huh? sorry don't get what you mean!

Comment: Instead of doing "If this is selected, then make this Ajax request to do X and submit this form to do Y" do "Submit this form. If the selected thing is in the data, do X. Do Y regardless"

Comment: that X/Y/Z thing always confused me lol.. anyway, i tried your very first suggestion and did n't work:      `success: function(data){
      $(thisForm).submit();
     } `

Comment: You've not calling the submit method on the form, you're calling it on  a jQuery object. The jQuery submit method triggers a submit event, which you don't want since that will stick you in a recursive loop.

Comment: Won't removing the `e.preventDefault();` suppose to simply make the form to do its default action "Regardless" and then run the AJAX as well?

Comment: also, what do you mean by this: You've not calling the submit method on the form, you're calling it on a jQuery object ?

Comment: No. It will start the Ajax, then submit the form, and never resolve the Ajax because a new page will load and the JavaScript execution environment will change.

Comment: The submit method on a DOM object works differently to the submit method on a jQuery object. You need to not use `$()` as that creates a jQuery object wrapper around the DOM object.

Comment: so how can I do the default action regardless then? because you say removing the `e.preventDefault();` won't have any affect! could you please explain it a bit better as I am well confused right now! I have a few `$()` in my code and I am not sure which one you are referring to?

Comment: I said removing `e.preventDefault();` would have a different effect to the one you desired. *I have a few $() in my code and I am not sure which one you are referring to?* — The one in the comment that you said you added when you tried my first suggestion.

Comment: Okay never mind, I think I'm gonna use a different approach as this clearly is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would u do that but yes there is a way:

```
 <script>
    var continue = true;
    $('#select').change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue === 'Yes') {
              $(function(){
                 $('form').submit(function(e){
                     var thisForm = $(this);
                     //Prevent the default form action
                    if(continue){
                        e.preventDefault();

                        //Post the form to the send script
                        $.ajax({
                             type: 'POST',
                             url: 'mySecond.php',
                             data: thisForm.serialize(),
                            //Wait for a successful response
                            success: function(data){
                                   continue = false;    
                                   $(thisForm).submit();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
      } else {

      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have the markup and full code but which line does it say the syntax error in? probably will get to it quickly :)

Comment: first line. `var continue = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Do the ajax call in the done callback.

```
     <button id="btnSave" type="submit" formaction="Save">Save</button>         
    $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
 var thisForm = $(this).closest( form ).serialize();
                $.ajax({  
                    url: '#',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false
                }).done(function(result) {
                        CallMySecond(thisForm );           
                });              

        }); 
function CallMySecond(data){
 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'mySecond.php',
              data: thisForm.serialize()
});
}
```